# saving only one attribute value out of two for an entity

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an entity named `Attribute`, it has 2 attributes `attribute_name` and `attribute_value`.

This `Attribute` `entity` is in on-to-many relationship with another entity named `Project`. 
I want to insert it like all the `attribute_name` for the one project to be same and only `attribute_value` to be different.

When I enter data, I take these attributes for `Attribute` entity in two different arrays and save them in go on clicking `Save` button using a `for` loop.

In order to keep `attribute_name` distinct, I check if they already exist in the data base,if yes then I only save `attribute_value`.
But it still inserts "attributes_name" as `NULL`. Data is getting saved for `attributes_name`.

So,when i click "save" button second time,I get double the textfield than before.which are empty.

```
NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Attributes" inManagedObjectContext:self.context]];
    [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"attribute_name in %@", applicationDelegate.attributesTextArray]];
    NSError * error;
    NSArray * anArray = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    for (int i = 0; i < [applicationDelegate.attributesTextArray count]; i++) {

        attributesObject = (Attributes*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Attributes" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
        if (anArray.count == 0) {
            attributesObject.attribute_name = [applicationDelegate.attributesTextArray objectAtIndex:i];
            attributesObject.attribute_value = [applicationDelegate.attributeGradesArray objectAtIndex:i];
        } else {
            attributesObject.attribute_value = [applicationDelegate.attributeGradesArray objectAtIndex:i];
        }

        [testArray addObject:attributesObject];
    } 
    for (int o=0; o<[testArray count]; o++) {

        NSData * retrievedData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ProjectManagedObject"];
        NSURL * retrievedUrl = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:retrievedData];
        NSManagedObjectID * projectObjectId = [applicationDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:retrievedUrl];

        projectObject = (Project*)[applicationDelegate.managedObjectContext objectWithID:projectObjectId];
        [projectObject addAttributesObject:[testArray objectAtIndex:o]];
        NSError * error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"UNABLE TO SAVE DATA: %@", [error userInfo]);
        }
```

What exactly is going wrong here ?

UPDATE:

```
NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription * entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError * error;
    NSArray * fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    NSLog(@"OBJECT FETCHED:%d", [fetchedObjects count]);

    if (fetchedObjects.count != 0) {
        Project * project_ = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:applicationDelegate.projectNumber];
        NSArray * saved_attributes = [project_.attributes allObjects];
        if (saved_attributes.count != 0) {
             //Update "attribute-value"
} else {
             // create new attribute and insert both "attribute_name" and "attribute_value" ?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line

```
attributesObject = (Attributes*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Attributes" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
```

creates a *new* "Attributes" object, independent of whether an object with a matching
name was found previously or not. If you want to updated an existing object, you must
set the properties of the fetched object instead of creating a new object.

Comment: So,I have to create only one instance of "Attribute" and then run the for loop ?

Comment: For each "attribute_name", you have to check if an object with that name already exists. If it exists, update the value. If it does not exist, create a new one with `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:...`

Comment: please check the UPDATE, is that what you are trying to make me understand ?

Comment: @Shailesh: I am not sure if I understand completely what you are trying. But in your first loop `for (int i = 0; i < [applicationDelegate.attributesTextArray count]; i++)` you always create a new "Attribute" object, even if the fetched array `anArray = [context executeFetchRequest:...]` already contains an Attribute object with that name.

Comment: Yes, I did it as in UPDATE, and it worked fine.
I have to say, Core data is somewhat tricky to grasp.

Comment: Though, this prevents duplication, it only updates my last row.